# What should the max file size be for a site background image?

Tags: html, css, image, optimization, load-time

The site I'm developing at the moment has a background image that is 250k after being optimized. It's being served from a CDN but obviously this is way too big, but before I go to the designer and ask her to remake the image, what is a file size I should recommend the image not be greater than?

P.S. this is video site and the main demo are younger people connecting via broadband.

Comment: A great one should be nice & repeatable ...

Comment: If the background image is important to the site's design, and if the design of the page is central, and if the site itself doesn't contain too much data, and if most of the targeted audience has highspeed Internet, in that case 250k would be acceptable. Depends on the image too. A gradient background image with 250k would be technically inept. On the other hand, a 2560x1600 NASA space picture with 250k is very light indeed.

Answer (score -1):

you can reduce image size by using photoshop...
just save that image as "Save for Web or devices..."